# How to check multiple conditions column based

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have a table from which I need to find out multiple rejection condition.

I have done following but not satisfied and looking for some good alternative.

```
declare @tbl table(id int identity, check1 float, check2 float, check3 float)

insert into @tbl (check1, check2, check3)
values (10, 15, 20), (5, 9, 8), (2, 3, 10)

select 
    id, 
    case 
        when check1 < 5 and check2 < 10 and check3 < 15 
           then 'check1 is less than 5 and check2 is less than 10 and check3 is less than 15'
        when check1 < 5 and check2 < 10 
           then 'check1 is less than 5 and check2 is less than 10'
        when check1 < 5 and check3 < 15 
           then 'check1 is less than 5 and check3 is less than 15'
        when check2 < 10 and check3 < 15 
           then 'check2 is less than 10 and check3 is less than 15'
        when check1 < 5 
           then 'check1 is less than 5 '
        when check2 < 10 
           then 'check2 is less than 10 '
        when check3 < 15 
           then 'check3 is less than 15 '
        else 'ok'
    end  
from 
    @tbl
```

Comment: Thanks Serkan for edit.

Answer (score 2):

You could use separate `CASE` expressions for each condition, and then try to aggregate all messages in some meaningful way.  Something like this:

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT id,
        CASE WHEN check1 < 5  THEN 'check1 is less than 5'  ELSE 'NA' END AS msg1,
        CASE WHEN check2 < 10 THEN 'check2 is less than 10' ELSE 'NA' END AS msg2,
        CASE WHEN check3 < 15 THEN 'check3 is less than 15' ELSE 'NA' END AS msg3
    FROM @tbl
)

SELECT
    id,
    msg1 + ', ' + msg2 + ', ' + msg3 AS message
FROM cte;
```

[image: screen capture from demo]

### Demo

Comment: For row 2, check2 is less than 10 and check3 is less than 15 should be printed,but not happening in this code.

Comment: @nextaxtion My output in fact prints that.  The only drawback to my solution is that I use `NA` placeholders which always appear.  So for row 1, you see `NA` three times, because all three checks passed.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. 
I do not want 'NA' and extra comma. please help.

Comment: Actually, while the answer by @Serkan should give you exactly what you want, I see no reason why you can't use the output from my CTE in your presentation layer.  It would seem easy enough to combine the individual messages in a language like Java or C#.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this.

```
select * 
    , ISNULL( STUFF(CASE WHEN check1 < 5 THEN 'AND check1 is less than 5 ' ELSE '' END
    + CASE WHEN check2 < 10 THEN 'AND check2 is less than 10 ' ELSE '' END
    + CASE WHEN check3 < 15 THEN 'AND check3 is less than 15 ' ELSE '' END, 1,4,''), 'ok')
from 
@tbl
```